# Launch vb .net application from VBScript

Tags: vb.net

Hopefully this is something simple I'm missing but I'm trying to figure out why I can't launch a newly created vb .net app using a vbscript that has no trouble launching other .exe files.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "WindowsApplication5.exe" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

The app can be started manually with no problems just like any other .exe  but this .vbs script treats it differently for some reason.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried it without chr(34). If I'm not mistaken run "Windowsapplication5.exe" is not the same as run Windowsapplication5.exe

Comment: Also, do put in the full path to the executable. My guess is that you have tested to do this with notepad, mspaint or something like that. Those have Paths setup in your OS which makes this code work. Whereas windowsapplication5 most definitely doesn't.

Comment: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/quickref/wshshell_run.html <- And the final tip. ",0" will launch the window hidden. So basically it runs in the background. Remove ,0 or set it to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put it as an answer to ease this up:

1. Remove chr(34) (Quite possibly optional, depends on wherther you have spaces in path)
2. Put full path to executable not just file name or put path in environment variables in OS. It doesn't matter if you run the script in the same folder as the executable is placed in.
3. Remove ,0 or change it to an other number since 0 runs it invisible (you'll find it in taskmanager in processes). Possible values found in http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/quickref/wshshell_run.html